# Too many open threads error

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I'm implementing a multithreaded Wget with the URLs in the Open Directory Project (ODP). I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log (Too many open files)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:78)
at ODP.run(ODP.java:103)
```

I've read that it's because it overpasses the limit of open file descriptors indicated in the system variable:  **cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max**

Is there a way to limit the number of threads that can be started at the same time? I thought that it did it automatically by the number of threads that could run the CPU.

Thank you!

**Edit:** this is the main loop inside the main method:

```
        while (rs.next ()) {                
            // Process entry
            String rsc = rs.getString ("resource");
            String tpc = rs.getString("topic");             
            (new ODP(rsc, tpc, rs.getString("description"))).start();   
            BufferedWriter outLog = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log", true));
    outLog.write(count + ": " + rsc + " | " + tpc  + "\n");
    outLog.close(); 
            ++count;                
        }
```

In the **ODP.run()** method I create a BufferedWritter:

```
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cat.split("/")[1] + ".webtrec", true));
        out.write(webtrec);
        out.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit the number of threads that can be started at
>   the same time?

Yes there is, by using some kind of thread pool. If you are using Java 1.5 and above, you are in luck; you can use [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to limit the number of concurrent threads.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confused between *threads* and *files* throughout your question.

Most operating systems place a limit on the number of file descriptors that a given process can have open.  This includes actual files on the filesystem, and usually includes sockets such as database or server connections as well.  (This has nothing whatsoever to do with the number of threads running within your process.)

If you're currently holding the maximum number of open file handles, your process won't be able to open any more.  This is typically a sign of a resource leak - i.e. you're not properly closing your I/O resources.  *Very* rarely, if your application legitimately needs to read from tens of thousands of files at the same time, would you need to increase the OS limit.

In your `ODP.run` method, are you creating `FileWriters` in a loop, but failing to call `close()` on them?

Comment: I put the code of how I handle the filewriter in the ODP.run method. As you see, I close it. Each thread opens a file descriptor so, the number of threads has something to do with the number of file descriptors at a specific instant.

Comment: I think if he spawn 10000 threads and each thread runs the above code he will get too many file open error too.